# Partial access from class type variable that points at an instance of a specialized type

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface, casting

When declaring a class type variable that points at an instance of a specialized type, the object type is determined by the instantiation rather than the declaration. Example:

```
Object o = new ArrayList<>();
if(o instanceof ArrayList)
System.out.println("ArrayList it is!");
```

So, ArrayList can only use the methods and properties of Object, in this case, even if I downcast it. How is it possible for an ArrayList to be only partly implemented, and wouldn't it make more sense if the type was made an Object?

Also, why is it possible to use the diamond inference without having a generic declaration in the first place?

Comment: This should print "ArrayList it is!", but "ArrayList<>" looks strange (Should be ArrayList or ArrayList<Object>)... Does this compile at all?

Comment: Try to rephrase your question because even the first sentence seems a little jibberish. "programming to an interface"? Do you mean implementing an interface? Why do you use "actual"?

Comment: @Stefan It compiles, surprisingly!

Comment: The type `ArrayList<>` is not the same as the type `ArrayList`. Try `(o instanceof ArrayList<>)`

Comment: Wouldn't type erasure make it such that ArrayList and ArrayList<> are the same type, Jacob?

Comment: @Chaba I realize that all classes have interfaces, I just wanted to clarify that I implement the interface of class Object rather than an Interface. 

My understanding is that we program to an interface when we declare a more abstract type than the actual implementation, hence making it possible to change the implementation.

Sorry about the confused wordiness, though.

Comment: @JacobKrall instanceof thinks of it as the same type.

Comment: No, we code to an Interface when we actually use a reference variable of Interface type and make it refer to an object whose class implements it as well. When you make a superclass reference refer to a subclass object you're using inheritance and (if you choose to) polymorphism as well.

Comment: I think you are confusing the terms "abstract class" and "interface."  An abstract class is a class that possesses partial implementation and which cannot be instantiated.  Only its subclasses may be instantiated into objects.  An interface never has any implementation.  It is meant only to indicate a contract between an API and its implementor.  The phrase "all classes have interfaces" is not strictly correct, since it is definitely possible to write a class that does not implement any interfaces.

Comment: @scottb Not striclty correct, that's true; but you can also have an Interface without an interface, like Serializable. Correct me if I'm wrong. Interfaces should really be called something else I think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you and I talk over the phone, then you are interfacing with only my voice, but it doesn't mean that the rest of me ceases to exist.  You are interfacing with that ArrayList as an Object, but it still has all the parts of an ArrayList - you just aren't interfacing with the other parts.

Comment: Oh my, this is confusing. It is implemented as an ArrayList, but only uses the interface of its declared type. Netbeans tells me that it is of type Object if I try to send it to a method that takes an ArrayList as a parameter. My guess is that the compiler thinks it's an Object at compile time, while it turns into an ArrayList at runtime. Aha!

Comment: No, the object is an ArrayList, but your variable `o` has been declared as type Object, so when using `o` as the handle, you can only access methods and fields available to the declared type, Object. The underlying object does not stop being an ArrayList, but variable `o` has access to nothing but the Object methods and fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object O = new ArrayList<>();
```

This particular code says; "Create an reference variable `o` of the type `Object` and point it to the new `ArrayList<>` object created on the heap."

The `instanceof` condition is checked when the jvm runs the code. Even if the reference variable is of the type `Object`, the actual object that is being created during the execution is the `ArrayList` object.

If you try using  any of the attributes/methods of the `ArrayList<>` using the `Object` reference variable `o`, e g `o.size()`;
The compiler will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

An empty diamond before Java 7 is a so called raw generic, and effectively it means that the container won't enforce any type constraints about the contained items, besides that they should be an Object. So basically `new ArrayList<>();` or `new ArrayList();` means `new ArrayList<Object>();`. This would basically throw away any type safety what Java generics provide.

@scottb reminded us: Java 7 gave a better usage for empty diamond: with type inference performed by the compiler your code can be a little terser and less error prone. Instead of `HashMap<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` you can say `HashMap<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();`.

For the first part: `java.lang.Object` is the type you perceive the `ArrayList` object if you refer to it using the `o` variable. The `instanceof` operator doesn't care about what is the type of `o`, it will precisely answer your question: is the thing which is "stored behind" the variable `o` is really an `ArrayList` or not.

Comment: I believe that this conclusion about the diamond operator is incorrect.  The diamond operator simply indicates that the compiler is determining the reference type by inference rather than by explicit declaration.  It is incorrect to say that the diamond operator means that the type is raw, weak, unspecified, or generic.  The compiler most assuredly will enforce strict type checking.

Comment: Thanks @scottb, you are correct, with Java 7 it has a new meaning.

Comment: I just had another aha! experience, thanks to your "stored behind the variable" clarification. If I create a new variable óf type ArrayList that points at the same object as the o variable, I gain access to all the public ArrayList methods, consequently accessing the same object that o has limited access to due to its implementation as an Object. I have learned so much from this. Thanks!